@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.12.3): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x401c795e transport errored
I'm trying to store data at firestore collection but getting this error again and again unable to store data on my messages collection.
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.12.3): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x401c795e transport errored
await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), {
        text: value,
        name: username,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        uid
      })

I want to store messages data to firestore

Okay so for everyone still struggling:
For me the error occurred because I created a database in Firestone trough the google console with a custom name instead of (default).
I fixed the issue by doing:

Deleting database with custom name
Deleting prebuilt (default) database because the database-mode was set to Datastore-Mode and not Native
Creating a new database with the name "(default)", and setting the mode to Native-Mode

If this isn't your case:
One way was explained on Github.
For what worked was also initializing it using experimentalForceLongPolling:
export const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true
})

instead of this:
export const db = getFirestore(app);


Creating with a custom name was the issue for me as-well.

Annoying issue but im happy it worked out

First one was the answer!!

This also worked for me.

Probably similar question to Firestore (9.6.6): Connection WebChannel transport errored:
According to @Kingsley
Initialize your firestore by doing:
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
  useFetchStreams: false,
});


Getting "'useFetchStreams' does not exist in type 'FirestoreSettings'" in Firebase 11.0.2

I had this issue, I fixed it by just amending this in the Cloud Firestore rules:
rules_version = '2'; 
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
    // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
    // your rules
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2025, 2, 7);
    }
  }
}

The comment should be self explanatory, but this cuts out all the read and write after 30 days, just edit the timestamp.date value to a further date
Not sure if this applies to you but I fixed it this way
Hope this helps
